# Send vairables to php via bash CURL

Tags: php, linux, curl, post, steam

I have a code like this:

```
<?php

$steamid64="76561197987276114"; //YOUR STEAM ID 64

echo "<br><br>Steamid32: ".getSteamId32($steamid64);
echo "<br><br>Steamid64: ".getSteamID64(getSteamId32($steamid64)); // 76561197985756607

//OBTER STEAM ID 64

function getSteamID64($id) {
    if (preg_match('/^STEAM_/', $id)) {
        $parts = explode(':', $id);
        return bcadd(bcadd(bcmul($parts[2], '2'), '76561197960265728'), $parts[1]);
    } elseif (is_numeric($id) && strlen($id) < 16) {
        return bcadd($id, '76561197960265728');
    } else {
        return $id; // We have no idea what this is, so just return it.
    }
}


function parseInt($string) {
    //    return intval($string);
        if(preg_match('/(\d+)/', $string, $array)) {
            return $array[1];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
function getSteamId32($id){
    // Convert SteamID64 into SteamID

    $subid = substr($id, 4); // because calculators are 
    $steamY = parseInt($subid);
    $steamY = $steamY - 1197960265728; //76561197960265728

    if ($steamY%2 == 1){
    $steamX = 1;
    } else {
    $steamX = 0;
    }

    $steamY = (($steamY - $steamX) / 2);
    $steamID = "STEAM_0:" . (string)$steamX . ":" . (string)$steamY;
    return $steamID;

}
?>
```

The question is: How do I make $steamid64 readable? I mean, without form. So it could be posted by curl from linux bash and reply (return $steamID;) received.

Sorry for a very newb question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking? Without form? What do you mean by that?
Because if you run this php in curl, you will get the output you wanted

Comment: I meant that I don't need an interface for this page. And what I want is a way to modifty this code, so this: $steamid64="76561197987276114"; value can be posted by curl and proper response received according to posted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i voted to close your question as unclear, but my best guess is that you want to change

```
<?php

$steamid64="76561197987276114"; //YOUR STEAM ID 64
```

to

```
<?php

$steamid64=$_POST['steamid64']??''; //YOUR STEAM ID 64
if(empty($steamid64) || !is_string($steamid64)){
    http_response_code(400);
    die("missing POST parameter steamid64!");
}
```

then you can do

```
curl -d "steamid64=76561197987276114" http://127.0.0.1/page.php
```

(but again, idk what you're asking, hence the close-vote.)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. Marked as solution.